# Does System.Linq.Dynamic support .net 4.5?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

In nuget, it says that System.Linq.Dynamic supports .net 3.5 and 4.0
Does System.Linq.Dynamic works well with .Net 4.5. If not, is there alternative?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? If not you can always try to build your `Linq.Expressions` by hand, or you can try `Roslyn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why not: `

> .NET Framework 4.5 is a high compatible in-place update that replaces
>   .NET Framework 4

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. In general Microsoft are pretty hot on backwards compatibility.